# Searching txt file for multiple names in multiple columns

Tags: python

I am trying to scan a txt file for certain file names in the first two columns. If I find a line in the txt file with the file name, I would like to print that line in the txt file. For example, the file names I am looking for are

```
File1 
File2
File3
File4
```

The txt file that I want to scan these file names in look something like this:

```
File23 File65
File1 File32
File45 File2
File12 Fil67
File3 File99
```

The output I want to have would look something like this (only leaving the lines with the file names that I am looking for:

```
File1 File32
File45 File2
File3 File99
```

Here is the code that I am currently trying to do this with but I dont get any output:

```
newcatalog = open(dir+'newS34catalog.txt', "r")
searchlinesnew = newcatalog.readlines()
newcatalog.close()

files = open(dir+'filesiwanttofind.txt',"r")
searchfiles = files.readline()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesnew):
    if searchfiles in line:
        for l in searchlinesnew[i:i+3]:
            print(l,)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to do it that works and avoids reading entire files into memory since everything is processed line-by-line:

```
with open(dir+'filesiwanttofind.txt', "r") as wanted:
    wantedfiles = [line.strip() for line in wanted]

with open(dir+'newS34catalog.txt', "r") as newcatalog:
    for line in newcatalog:
        if any(wanted in line.split() for wanted in wantedfiles):
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Output:

```
File1 File32
File45 File2
File3 File99
```

Comment: This seems like it would work but it won't stop running... paused at the if any(wanted in line.split() for wanted in wantedfiles): line

Comment: hlku2334: All I can say is it worked for me with both Python 2 and 3. However I did notice it was doing something unnecessary (but harmless), so have updated it. See if it works any better for you now.

Comment: Would it matter if my new catalog file has multiple columns but only the first two would contain the file name?

Comment: hlku2334: As written it will search all the columns on each line, regardless of how many there are, so having more than two wouldn't make it "pause" (or hang). It would be easy to make it only search the first two columns. However, I'd like to know whether it Is working otherwise for you now?

Comment: The catalog file is a large file, so I let it run completely through (this is why I thought it was "paused") but still, nothing was printed.

Comment: hlku2334: Sorry, that's not enough information for me to determine what's causing the problem for you. As I said before, it's working fine for me. I suggest you put a `print('done')` at the very end to make sure it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say for sure without knowing the content of the files and expected (desired) output, but the check `searchfiles in line` seems wrong: you're checking that the string read from filesiwanttofind.txt is a substring of the line you are looking at, which I suspect isn't what you indended.

Answer (score 0):

If the content of the file is fixed and always be `File1`, ... then this may be what you need. Suppose each line of files are read into `x, y` `list`

```
x = ["File1", "File2", "File3", "File4"]

y = ["File23 File65", "File1 File32","File45 File2", "File12 File67", "File3 File99"]

y = [item.strip().split(" ") for item in y]  # turn it into list for searching

results = []
for filename in x:
    for searchstr in y:
        if filename in searchstr:
            results.append(searchstr)

print(results)
# result: [['File1', 'File32'], ['File45', 'File2'], ['File3', 'File99']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could store the filenames you want to find in a set for fast (O(1)) lookups.

Then you can read from the file line by line, split on a space and check if any of the files resulting from the split are in the set. If so, print the line. The code is shown below

```
filename = dir+'newS34catalog.txt'
newcatalog = open(filename, 'r')
lookup_table = {"File1", "File2", "File3", "File4"}

for line in newcatalog:
    filenames = line.split(" ")
    if filenames[0] in lookup_table or filenames[1] in lookup_table:
        print line # you can also append to a results tuple or lists depending on your required output.
```

I hope the code is understandable.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to get your code working while making as few changes as possible. I've also explained some of the changes I've made so you can understand it better.

```
searchfiles = files.read().splitlines()
```

files.readline() would only read the first line. While you could use files.readlines() it would give you the newline character at the end of each line

```
if any(s in line.split() for s in searchfiles):
```

In your initial code your searchfiles variable was a single line now it is a list of lines. We are splitting the line variable as a list for cases where the string you are searching for isn't in the first column

The full solution comes out to be

```
newcatalog = open('newS34catalog.txt', "r")
searchlinesnew = newcatalog.readlines()
newcatalog.close()

files = open('filesiwanttofind.txt',"r")
searchfiles = files.read().splitlines()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlinesnew):
    if any(s in line.split() for s in searchfiles):
        print(line, end="")
```

I was going to write a more efficient solution but Martineau has written a much better solution than I had thought of. 
So I'm just going to add it here as a single comprehensive answer.

```
with open(dir+'filesiwanttofind.txt', "r") as wanted:
wantedfiles = []
for line in wanted:
    wantedfiles.extend(line.split())

with open(dir+'newS34catalog.txt', "r") as newcatalog:
    for line in newcatalog:
        if any(wanted in line.split() for wanted in wantedfiles):
            print(line.rstrip())
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're after speed and lightness, set membership checking and running the entire search through a single generator pipeline is gonna give you the best results. The code below could have been optimized further but this seems to be the middleground between readability and high performance. Hope it helps. If you haven't already, look into beazely-style python generators, they're awesome and blatantly add magnitudes of speed to your code.

```
# create a set of targets to quickly look up targets
targets = {i.strip() for i in open('targets.txt','r') if i.strip()}

# clean trailing whitespace on each line
results = (i.strip() for i in open('haystack.txt','r'))
# only process lines with a space
results = (i for i in results if ' ' in i)
# filter lines that have words that intersect with targets
results = (i for i in results if targets.intersection(i.split(' ')[:2]))

# display the results
for line in results:
    print(line)
```